# Edited texture not replacing old texture in render

Tags: rendering, uv, texture-painting

I was working on a tower and painted my own texture for it. I saved halfway though and took a break.
When I returned to my little project, I could paint on the image and it shows up in the material view but not the render.
I did everything in my power but still couldn't understand why?

I have used:

- Nodes, including mapping and insert UV coordinates.
- Unwrap UVs
- Used lights
- Deleted and replace nodes
- Deleted and replace Mat
- Removed image and replace it
- Reload image
- Painted on mesh

Even though use blender, I am not a programmer. So I find it really helpful if someone could give me an answer.

[image: blender showing the object in render mode and the edited texture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No programming required to paint in blender. <sub><sup>:)</sup></sub>

It looks to me like you simply did not save your image after you painted it.

Blender will display the changed image in the viewport, but until you save it blender will not render it (and your work will be lost if you close blender, even after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>).

With the mouse in the *UV/Image Editor* press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, or from the header *Image* > *Save Image*. That writes the changes you made in blender to an image file, actually saving your image. Now your render will look as excepted.

---

Here is an animated gif showing me painting on an object in the 3D view, then rendering it without saving the edited image.
[image: animated gif]

Comment: It *should* update in realtime with viewport render however (only tested with cycles), as it appears the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @gandalf3 My tests do not render a painted image in the viewport without first saving it.

Comment: It completely work. I knew it was suppose to be a easy answer to the biggest problem in the world. Thank you David!